# Change color of item label including item[CUSTOM]

Tags: lists, environments, itemize

I need to create a custom environment for a list which takes a parameter as item label and colors all the item labels red. Additionally, I need to be able to specify a different label for some items using the optional parameter of the item command. This different label should also be red.

So far I have the following code which works fine but I can't get the color of the ### label to red.

```
\newenvironment{textitemize}[1]{ 
  \renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\color{red}#1} 
  \begin{itemize}
}{
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{textitemize}{ad}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{textitemize}
```

**EDIT**

In the end it should like on the following picture, where the first line is a usage example.
I would need a local counter and the items should be created by using only the `\item` command no other custom command.

[image: It should look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{font=\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}[label=ad]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is the updated version of the code that also inlcudes the counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{font=\color{red}\bfseries\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}[label=ad~\arabic*]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
  \item more text
  \item another item
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine, but I didn't include that I need to make the label bold and add a custom counter which is only incremented every non-different label.
I don't see how I can achieve this with enumitem...

Comment: To also make the labels bold, you could use `font=\color{red}\bfseries`. Regarding teh counter: I currently don't really understand how tht kind of counter should look like? Could you add more information on the desired output?

Comment: @cranckstorm: I have added an update to my answer to also include the counter.

Comment: Your answer is shorter and cleaner than mine therefore I have accepted it as correct - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @lendriis's answer, I add a counter to count special item with `\myitem`. I don't know if you want a global counter or a local one. So I define `\globalmyitem` and `\localmyitem` to switch between `global` and `local`. And please add the extra requirement you mentioned in @lendriis's answer's comment to you question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{font=\bfseries\itshape\color{red}, label=ad \themyitem}
\newcounter{myitem}
\setcounter{myitem}{1}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item \stepcounter{myitem}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalmyitem}{\setcounter{myitem}{1}\def\patch@myitem{}}
\newcommand{\localmyitem}{\def\patch@myitem{\setcounter{myitem}{1}}}
\def\patch@myitem{}
\xpretocmd{\myitemize}{\patch@myitem}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{Global counter}

\globalmyitem
\fbox{list 1}
\begin{myitemize}
  \myitem Foo
  \myitem Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{myitemize}
\fbox{list 2}
\begin{myitemize}
  \myitem Foo
  \myitem Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{myitemize}

\switchcolumn
\section*{Local counter}

\localmyitem
\fbox{list 1}
\begin{myitemize}
  \myitem Foo
  \myitem Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{myitemize}
\fbox{list 2}
\begin{myitemize}
  \myitem Foo
  \myitem Bar
  \item[\#\#\#] foo
\end{myitemize}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by renewing the `\item` command and, depending whether the optional parameter was supplied or not, either reusing the old `\item` or writing my own prefix. See the code below.

**Packages**

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xifthen}% provides \isempty test
```

**Definition**

```
% used for counting list entries
\newcounter{myCounter}

% myPrefix will return the prefix for list items set by textitemize
\newcommand{\myPrefix}{}

% set myPrefix and start itimize environment
\newenvironment{textitemize}[1] {
    \renewcommand{\myPrefix}[1]{#1 }
    \begin{itemize}
}{\end{itemize}}

% redefine item as olditem because this will be reused
\let\olditem\item
% if optional parameter is present call \olditem with it, otherwise add custom prefix and counter
\renewcommand{\item}[1][ ]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
        {\olditem[\color{red}\textit{\textbf{\myPrefix~\stepcounter{myCounter}\themyCounter}}]}% if #1 is empty
        {\olditem[\color{red}{\textbf{#1}}]}% if #1 is not empty
    
}
```

**Usage:**

```
\begin{textitemize}{ad}
    \item Was wir wollen.
    \item Was wir haben.
    \item Was wir tun.
    \item[\#\#\#] Dieser Eintrag tanzt aus der Reihe.
    \item
    \item
\end{textitemize}
```

**Result**
[image: Result]